In the middle of qsort, is there a way to stop it?
qsort is an essential part of the standard C library in all platforms. In the compare function introduced to this function, I may conclude that two items are identical and I decide not to continue the process of sorting elements.
How can I inform this to qsort not to continue sorting?

Not to the qsort() function in the C library. You can write your own sorting function (with the Quick Sort or other algorithm) and break your function during the process. Let's say the comparison function for your function returns -1, 0, or 1 as the standard...or -42 (or whatever) to force a premature stop

You can't make qsort stop.  However you can set a flag in your comparison function that returns "equal" for every call made thereafter.

...longjmp might do the job, if I'm not missing some sort of undefined behavior? But this is an extremely unusual use case, and if I absolutely had to interrupt a sort in progress from the comparator, I'd definitely go with a custom sort routine.

@MarkRansom Yeah, I certainly set the flag not to process further elements. But, I don't know returning which one leads to faster end, -1, 0 or 1.

I would expect longjmp to do the job, but longjmp is pretty nasty.  And if your program is multithreaded then you might still need a custom sort function to handle the jump buffer safely.

@pmg Thank you. Your explicit answer means there's no way other than I write my own function. But reinventing the wheels may not be a good idea. qsort is written to have the best performance.

@user2357112 How can I long jump from a function to another function?! I think it's not possible in C.

@JohnBollinger You're serious about longjmp?! What is it? Is it a keyword in C? I've never used it before.

Are you sure you need to do this?  Have you profiled your program and found that qsort() is consuming a large proportion of its runtime, or of the runtime of some time-critical behavior?  Are you sure that curtailing the sort early in the event that identical elements are identified would significantly improve that?  Have you looked for algorithmic improvements in the calling code that would reduce the number of qsort() calls?

Depending on the data you want to sort, radix sort (and many other algos) may be faster than any O(n log n) sort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Non-comparison_sorts

Hmm, not really sure. If it's safe in a non-multi-threaded environment, why should I wait until the end, while I don't want to pay attention to the result because of the identical items?

Thank you for introducing radix sort, but qsort is a ready-to-use function. I'm not going to write any implementations for a new kind of sort.

@hamidi, longjmp() is a function in the C standard library, used together with setjmp() to perform "non-local" control transfers.  Which is almost always a bad idea, but C lets you implement bad ideas.

@JohnBollinger I think you're right. I wondered about it too. How can it handle call stack?

Thank you all. I got the answer I was looking for.

Can you show me an example scenario where a comparator function (which only knows about two items to compare) can determine that all the remaining items in the collection are already sorted and therefore the qsort function can stop early? I find it very difficult to think of such a scenario.

Worst case the two elements that you compare as equal might be the last two that qsort is comparing.  Are you sure this is going to result in time savings in the typical case?

@k314159 I took the question to mean that once they identified two equal elements, they didn't need the sort anymore.

@k314159 Only two identical items are enough to cancel acceptance of the whole elements. They should make a unique list.

Yeah exactly...

What is the reasoning behind deciding to stop if two items are identical? qsort is unlikely to call the comparator function with the identical item for both arguments (I expect any good design would not, although this is not specified in the C standard). If might call the comparator function for two items that are distinct items but are equal-valued according to the comparator. But happening upon equal-valued items during the sort does not mean the sort is complete. This could happen at the start of the qsort, when no work at all has been done.

With the longjmp way, you call setjmp in the function where you call qsort, and call longjmp in your comparator. Since you seem to never have heard of longjmp you can take it as a chance to learn about it, but as others commented it is generally a bad idea to use in real codes. Also you have to read the documentation carefully to learn the caveats or you could end up with hard-to-debug UBs fairly easily.

@WeijunZhou Sure, it was interesting for me that we've such a function and I'm still wondering how can it be possible. What can it do with stack?!

@EricPostpischil You're right. The list would not be sorted, but it's not important. Because it includes non-unique elements. I certainly meant equal valued elements.

Avoiding danger of longjmp, I think I may create a thread to do the whole process of sorting and when it encounters a non-unique element, it just calls pthread_exit. But maybe the overhead of creating a thread and joining it in the main thread may be greater than letting qsort do the job until the end. :D

Just a thought experiment -- https://godbolt.org/z/br6acK6PY

@pmg Thank you :)
I couldn't realize it though

@hamidi, on a stack-based machine, one of the jobs of setjmp() is to record enough information to restore the stack to its state as-of the setjmp() call (with some caveats).  That part may be as simple storing the values of the stack pointer and stack frame pointer at that time, so that they can be restored upon a longjmp().  Such a restoration discards all stack frames on top of the one in which the setjmp() call was performed, all at once.

Yeah, it doesn't seem a safe solution. Besides, I think the debugger won't be able to keep track of the program flow.

I suspect your debugger would surprise you, @hamidi.  But again, as I was implying (much) earlier, it is not worthwhile considering anything remotely along these lines unless you are sure that a solution has at least a chance of producing a meaningful benefit for you.

By the way, if detecting duplicates is the only reason you have to sort, then sorting is probably itself the wrong choice.  A hash table would be a better tool for that, and it would naturally support stopping at the first match found.

aye, I was about to suggest this. Inserting into a good hash table implementation is (amortized) O(1) (in all but impossible circumstances).

@MarkRansom "However you can set a flag in your comparison function that returns "equal" for every call made thereafter." --> that risks UB for the compare function to behave in a manner inconsistent with prior calls. "When the same objects (consisting of size bytes, irrespective of their current positions in the array) are passed more than once to the comparison function, the results shall be consistent with one another. That is, for qsort they shall define a total ordering on the array, and for bsearch the same object shall always compare the same way with the key."

It looks like the XY-problem. What task are you solving?

Do you know anything about the values beforehand, such as the range of values?  If the range is relatively small, you can effectively use a radix sort which will be O(n).  qsort will at best be O(n log n).

@ikegami even though any individual insertion is O(1), you need to do it n times so the overall complexity becomes O(n).

@Mark Ransom, Of course. And O(n) is way better than quicksort's O(n^2). It's very likely to be faster except possibly for trivial inputs.

@ikegami I thought quicksort was O(n log n) which is why it's so popular?

No, I need the list to be sorted, as well as unique.
What's XY-problem? I'm just going to obtain an ordered unique list.

@Mark Ransom, Its worst case is O(n^2). And it performs the worse for already-sorted and almost-sorted lists, which is a common scenario. Perl switched from using quicksort to mergesort for its builtin long long ago (which also has the benefit of being a stable sort).

@hamidi, You didn't ask to get a sorted array of the distinct values. To get that, sorting then removing the duplicates would be the simplest. But if you have a lots of duplicates, removing them beforehand using a hash of seen values might be beneficial.

@hamidi: Your question does not state you need the list to be sorted. It says you want to stop sorting if two identical items are found. It does not say why. From the posted question, there is no indication whether the motive is (a) Just test whether a list contains two identical items, returning a true/false indication about that or (b) If a list contains duplicate items, report an indication of that, and, if it does not, then sort the items. Or possibly something else. You should edit the question to clearly and fully state what the computation to be performed is.

XY problem

I'm not going to choose one of identical items, since their properties differ. User should not enter items which are identical. An error should be show to them in such a condition.

So it's an exceptional situation. There's no need to optimize that. Just sort the whole thing, then check for dupes. That's assuming you need them sorted at all, which you just dropped from the description of what you want to do.

To a simple problem, there's no need to think so complicated, @EricPostpischil

@hamidi: There is a need to specify what the problem is. Other people cannot give you an appropriate solution if they do not know what the problem is. If you ask for a method to stop a qsort, and people give you a method to stop a qsort, that is not a solution for a problem of “Sort these items if they are all distinct, but report a problem if they are not.” There is no reason for you to be obstinate and withhold information. Edit the question to clearly and fully specify the problem.

@JohnBollinger: Please provide your suggestion as the solution so that I may confirm it. Thanks

@hamidi, I did not make a suggestion, though I tried hard to get you to consider simply abandoning the whole idea.  I also spent some words on longjmp, including responding to your followup inquiries, but you absolutely should not take that as a suggestion that you actually should use longjmp to terminate a qsort() run early.

@JohnBollinger Yeah, but you described its pros and cons. Although you were not alone and I got help from the whole whom I really thank, I found that there's no straightforward way for aborting qsort and it helped.

Based on your comments, your “real” question is how to effectively check a list for duplicates (X). You thought the solution was being able to interrupt qsort (Y) which is what you asked about.  We’re telling you that you’re approaching the problem the wrong way and should consider alternatives.

My question was as I described. In the middle of qsort callback function, I realize that I don't want to continue sorting and consume unnecessary resource and time, because I've realized that the list if not a proper list because it contains duplicate items. It's really simpler than what you try to make it hard!

@dbush: When people will not cooperate, I recommend to just vote to close the question (as needs clarification). It is not worth commenting or answering when somebody will not make simple edits or will not accept that there are alternatives or are issues that need to be distinguished or clarified. Once a person has decided their point of view is the only one, it apparently prevents them from seeing the confusion or alternatives that other people are aware of. Even if it is just something simple like they know context that clarifies the question but that is not present in their post.

@EricPostpischil I wonder why you get angry! The question is asked, then answered, and the answers and discussions about it has been approved and realized by the participants and the one who asked has got his answer and found what to do, and at the end you come and still need clarification of the source of the question! Don't you think this is you who need clarification? So why you decide for others?! You may simply leave this thread, if it bothers you.

@hamidi: Who says I am angry? I just recommended steps to improve Stack Overflow. You have used Stack Overflow as a personal service and are neglecting how it serves the community generally, not just you. It is supposed to serve as a durable repository of questions and answers for future users. As part of that, each question should be fully specified and clear. And answers should be given in answers, not comments. Comments are ephemeral; they can disappear at any time. The proper way to serve that, long established in Stack Overflow, is to edit the question to make it clear…

… and for answers to be posted as answers, not comments. If you are not going to participate in the community (just take for yourself and not help others), why do you care whether this question is closed or not? You say you have your answer. Closing this question will not take that away from you. But it will clean up Stack Overflow; it will remove from search results a question that is not of the quality we want to help future users. You could easily cooperate and simply edit the question to state what the actual goal is, with context, as other people have asked you to…

… You choose not to, so the question should be closed. That is not about anger; it is simply about improving Stack Overflow.

The problem as I understand it so far is “I have a list of items which could be sorted by qsort. If there are any duplicate items on the list, I wish to report an error, and the list will be discarded (its memory will be freed). Otherwise, I want to sort the list. What is a good algorithm for this? I was considering using qsort and aborting the sort in the comparison function if the comparison function detects a duplicate. This has an advantage of using the sort to detect equal items instead of doing it separately. Can qsort be aborted in a defined way?”

If that is a correct description of what you want to do, I could write that up and put it into the question.

FYI comments are not intended for extended discussion. Perhaps move to [chat] if this needs to be continued.

No, I don't think any further discussions required.


How can I inform this to qsort not to continue sorting?

qsort() can not be informed without UB.
One way not to do it
Do not do this: Have the compare function perform differently part way through the sorting.
The compare function is bound by

When the same objects (consisting of size bytes, irrespective of their current positions in the array) are passed more than once to the comparison function, the results shall be consistent with one another. That is, for qsort they shall define a total ordering on the array, and for bsearch the same object shall always compare the same way with the key.  C23dr § 7.24.5 4

To do so otherwise invites undefined behavior (UB).

A way that might work: a SWAG.
Put the qsort() call in its own thread and exit the thread early when desired from the compare function.  Of course an early return may leave the array in an indefinite state.

I now see OP was considering a thread solution.

This doesn’t seem like an answer.

As soon as the compare callback function finds that there's at least one duplicate item in the whole array, it's not important how will the array be, because soon it'll be freed and thrown away. I need the list not to consist of duplicate elements.

I prefer using thread, as I suggested before.

@hamidi, concerning it's not important how will the array be: to be clear, adjusting the compare function to return a different result result, given the same input as before, is UB:  exiting the thread or some jump remain possibilities to analyze.  As the question had "inform this to qsort", I wanted to make clear this is not a good approach.

@Ry- From a C point of view, it addresses a an issue discussed by OP and in comments, that of somehow altering the functionality of the qsort() compare function. This approach is ill advised given the cite in this answer -thus a partial answer.
